# Setting javascript function for all <a>

Tags: lightbox

I have a lightbox script that Im using:

```
<a class="lb-image-link" href="images/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="lb-set">
<img class="lb-image" src="images/thumb-image-1.jpg" width="150" height="150"/></a>
```

But for my clients sake to use CMS software I need to make the `data-lightbox="lb-set"` function work for all `<a>` tag on the page or to make it work as a class somehow if possible.

The page is HTML, how can I make this work? Im guessing I need to create javascript for this. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to learn some jquery, if you are not already familiar with it

http://jquery.com/

and then you can easily attach a function to all click events on every a tag on the page with something like:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {

      //your lighbox code goes here ...
});
```

EDIT

With the lightbox2 script you are using it doesn't look like there is a way to assign it to a group of links on your page based on class or tag type, so the above function is not relevant. At a quick glance, if you stick with that script the only way to have it work on multiple links on the same page is to include a unique data-lightbox="" attribute in each link, eg.

```
<a href="img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption">image #1</a>
<a href="img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2" title="My caption">image #2</a>
<a href="img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-3" title="My caption">image #3</a>
```

There are other lightbox scripts that allow you to set the lightbox based on tag type or class, for instance http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ allows you to do the following:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="big_image_1.jpg">image #1</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="big_image_2.jpg">image #2</a>
```

and then use the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>
```

the above essentially attaches the fancybox lightbox to anything that has a class="fancybox"

Not sure if that helps - there may not be much difference for you having to add a unique data-lightbox="image-3" to each link as apposed to adding a standard class to them :-)

Glen

Comment: you should check out vanilla-js framework, way faster than jq

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although I am really new to javascript and Im trying to learn but what am I suppose to put in "//your lighbox code goes here ..."

Comment: Which lightbox script are you using - do you have the download url for it?